# is the usage of article "a" correct in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

the headline is:

"Going Back to Eat in Midtown, Where the Main Dish Is New York

This often-maligned neighborhood is pulsing again with a variety, energy and deep history that are part of the city’s essence."

the part that puxxles me is: "with a variety, energy and deep history that" the way i see it is:

with a variety, with a energy amd with a deep history...... so having "a" before the word preceding the comma makes it wwird, unless i'm seeing it the wrong way, what you think?

Comment: Stylistically, the actual version as cited here is probably "best". But it would make absolutely no difference to the meaning if the first article were omitted, OR if you add an article before ***energy***, OR if you add articles before both ***energy*** AND ***deep history***. The only "unacceptable" stylistic choice would be to "delete" the first and/or second article, but then include the last one. Once you start deleting "predictably repeated" elements like that, you should stick with the process; it's stylistically appalling to stop then start (but still "syntactically valid").

Comment: Also note that the text as cited features the ***indefinite*** article *(**a**)*, but it could just as well have used the definite article *(**the**)*. Which wouldn't really change the meaning - it would just imply slightly more strongly that the city *does in fact* have its own "unique characteristics".

Comment: ...also also note that in principle we could have used an indefinite article for *...part of **a** city’s essence* - implying that ***all*** cities have such characteristics.

Comment: In my opinion the sentence is awkward, and is not a good example to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is too generous, but I believe that news publications are generally correct when it comes to grammar due to the strict editing and style guidelines they follow. It would be correct to say that "the neighborhood is pulsing with variety, energy, and deep history" as general descriptors but in this case the author is specifically referring to *a* variety, *an* energy, and *a* deep history unique to this place, which sets up the rest of the sentence to be able to refer to them as "part of the city's essence".